# Laravel / MySQL when using AVG (only count first row return on a given id) - how?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

My AVG(rank) will return 2 and 34 clicksSum in this case. But how can I get it to only count the first row of ranks? So that it will only take one rank of each keyword_id from each date in the interval.

```
$interval = \DB::table('keywords')
->selectRaw('keyword, url, AVG(rank) rankAvg, SUM(clicks) clicksSum ')
->join('ranks', 'keywords.id', '=', 'ranks.keyword_id')
->whereBetween('ranks.date', array('2018-07-20','2018-07-29'))
->orderBy('clicksSum', 'DESC')
->groupBy('keywords.id')
->paginate(50);

Table: Keywords
id keyword
1  test

Table: Ranks
id keyword_id rank url      clicks date
1  1          2    /test/   29     2018-07-28 
1  1          4    /test2/  5      2018-07-28
```

The goal I wish to achieve is getting rankAvg = 2 and clicksSum = 29.

There is a alot of data in the table, this is just a simple example.

Comment: Define 'first'.

Comment: I want to only count the first row for each keyword_id on each date.

Comment: Ok. Define 'first row'. Which one is 'first', and why?

Comment: That would be where rank is lowest

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql `max` and order by it

```
$interval = \DB::table('keywords')
->selectRaw('keyword, url, AVG(rank) rankAvg, SUM(clicks) clicksSum, max(clicks) as maxClicks')
->join('ranks', 'keywords.id', '=', 'ranks.keyword_id')
->whereBetween('ranks.date', array('2018-07-20','2018-07-29'))
->groupBy('keywords.id')
->orderBy('maxClicks')
->paginate(50);
```